# How do I separate a character column into two columns?

Tags: r, tidyr

This is what I have:

```
condition    uncomfortable
   <fct>             <dbl>
 fichero               1
 fichero               1
 realhero              1
 realhero              2
 ficvillain            4
 ficvillain            5
 realvillain           8
 realvillain           3
```

How can I get this:

```
fictionality    character type    uncomfortable
   
 fic                hero              1
 fic                hero              1
 real               hero              1
 real               hero              2
 fic                villain           4
 fic                villain           5
 real               villain           8
 real               villain           3
```

Perhaps `separate()` and `strsplit()` are useful here, but I don't know how to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `extract` from `tidyr` :

```
tidyr::extract(df, condition, c('fictionality', 'type'), '(fic|real)(hero|villain)')

# fictionality    type uncomfortable
#1          fic    hero             1
#2          fic    hero             1
#3         real    hero             1
#4         real    hero             2
#5          fic villain             4
#6          fic villain             5
#7         real villain             8
#8         real villain             3
```

Or in base R :

```
transform(df, fictionality = sub('hero|villain', '', condition), 
              type = sub('fic|real', '', condition))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(condition = c("fichero", "fichero", "realhero", 
"realhero", "ficvillain", "ficvillain", "realvillain", "realvillain"
), uncomfortable = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

To supplement ***@RonakShah***'s answer, you can also use `separate()` from `tidyr` and set its separator as `"(?<=a)(?=b)"`.

```
tidyr::separate(df, condition, c('fictionality', 'type'), sep = '(?<=fic|real)(?=hero|villain)')

#   fictionality    type uncomfortable
# 1          fic    hero             1
# 2          fic    hero             1
# 3         real    hero             1
# 4         real    hero             2
# 5          fic villain             4
# 6          fic villain             5
# 7         real villain             8
# 8         real villain             3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain what ?<= and ?= mean in the later part of the code?

Comment: @Ruth you could search *"regular expression look ahead and look behind"* for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance! I will search that.